# Environment variables in motd not working

Tags: login, root, environment-variables, motd

I’m trying to send user login logs to my email with the users name and location. After making the script I found that environment variables can’t run in this script, I’m hoping that someone out there can help me get this working even if it’s a security problem. 
Thanks for your time

/etc/update-motd.d/99-footer

```
ssmtp -oi me@gmail.com << EOF
To: me@gmail.com
Subject: Login

$SUDO_USER" from "$SSH_CLIENT

EOF
```

email output is

```
Subject: Login  
 from
```

Comment: `$SUDO_USER" from "$SSH_CLIENT` is somewhat strange syntax. try to use `"$SUDO_USER from $SSH_CLIENT"` or even better ${SUDO_USER} etc. But this woh't help, I guess - where are the environment variables SUDO_USER and SSH_CLIENT defined?

Comment: idk where the environment variables are defined

Comment: Type "set" and you will get a list of all the current variables. If you want something to persist put it in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

Comment: i give it a try but no luck. thanks for trying virpara

Answer (score 2):

As an experiment, I added an `env` command (equivalent to `printenv`) to the end of `/etc/update-motd.d/99-footer` on my Ubuntu 12.04 system.

When I logged in again, the following lines were added to the end of my `/etc/motd`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
```

So `$PATH` and `$PWD` are the *only* environment variables that are set when `99-footer` is running. That's why `$SUDO_USER` and `$SSH_CLIENT` aren't being expanded.

You need to send that e-mail from somewhere else, not from the process that updates `/etc/motd`.

Answer (score -1):

If you change the script to:

```
echo "To: me@gmail.com
Subject: Login

$SUDO_USER from $SSH_CLIENT

" | ssmtp -oi me@gmail.com
```

Note use of double quotes. Variables should then be substituted.